# Jacobian of a semistable curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, jacobians, picard-group, neron-models

My question is about the proof of Example 8 in section 9.2 of the book "Neron models." There we have a semistable curve $X$ over an algebraically closed field $K$ and we let $\pi\colon \widetilde{X} \rightarrow X$ be its normalization. We have established the surjectivity of the natural pullback map $\pi^*: \mathrm{Pic}^0_{X/K} \rightarrow \mathrm{Pic}^0_{\widetilde{X}/K}$ of $K$-group schemes (the target being an abelian variety) and we would like to investigate the kernel $T := \mathrm{Ker}(\pi^*)$. In particular, we would like to show that $T$ is a torus. My question is: why is $T$ a torus?

The argument given for this in loc. cit. seems to be that $T$ being a torus somehow follows from an exact sequence of the form
$$1 \rightarrow K^* \rightarrow \prod_{i = 1}^r K^* \rightarrow \prod_{j = 1}^N K^* \rightarrow \mathrm{Pic}(X) \rightarrow \mathrm{Pic}(\widetilde{X}) \rightarrow 1. $$
I understand the proof of this sequence, but this sequence seems to be entirely about abelian groups (at least with the level of justification given in the cited proof), so I fail to understand how it manages to imply the structure of $T$ as an algebraic group.

I would be very grateful if someone could spell out the argument or provide any clarifying comments.

Comment: What is written there is not at all a rigorous proof. But it contains nearly all of the key ideas. One has to think carefully about the functorial meaning of the entire calculation in terms of ${\rm{R}}^i(f_{\ast})$'s for the structure map $f$ between fppf sites to turn it into a rigorous justification (and if $K$ isn't algebraically closed then one has to use the hard fact that the non-smooth points are $K$-etale to get Weil-restricted GL$_1$'s attached to non-smooth points for describing the relevant tori over the ground field). The proof of Prop. 9 gives ample inspiration (read ahead!).

Comment: Would you mind writing out (an outline of) the details as an answer? That would be extremely helpful. I've read the proof of Prop. 9 but that is more of the same: start out by pretending to work with Zariski sheaves, then move to other sites with no justification (or mentioning to which ones: big etale or small etale?); as a bonus put in some cryptic references to Serre's book (written in pre-EGA terminology). Here are the points of Ex. 8 that seem most obscure to me: (1) If we are to carry out the argument in the fppf site, then why is (*) exact (how to deal with arbitrary base change)? ...

Comment: ... (2) How is $\pi_* \mathbb{G}_m$ representable on the fppf site ($\pi$ is only finite, not locally free); same for the quotient? (I guess your helpful remark about the residue fields at non-smooth points is important here; on this subject, one should refer to III.2.7 of Freitag-Kiehl for a proof of the related remark preceding Thm. 7). (3) If one works in the fppf site, why is $R^1f_* \mathscr{Q} = 0$ (again how to deal with arbitrary base change)?

Comment: I don't feel like writing out more on this; it is a pain on a computer and I figured out all of these things as a student/postdoc by thinking over long periods of time (coming back to it later when I knew more). I think you should put in more effort on your own for this one instead of asking on MO.  The struggle will be good for you. (The Freitag-Kiehl reference you identified is the one I had in mind for the separability, by the way.) I never claimed  $\pi_{\ast}(\mathbf{G}_m)$ is representable; it's just a sheaf. Try to use the etale site first; it may suffice!

Comment: @QuestionMark: There are definitely other references for this, as well.  If memory serves (and I often get these things wrong), Altman-Kleiman prove this in their paper on compactifications of Picard schemes of semistable curves.

Comment: @user74230: I have already put in a number of hours into this (hence the decision to ask on MO), and I don't feel that it is right that the reader should be expected to redo some of the proofs. Of course, the struggle is useful in the end (but also very time-consuming).

Comment: @JasonStarr: Thanks for mentioning this (I was hoping for an alternative reference). Kleiman's paper in FGA explained was very helpful in clearing up some obscurities in Chapter 8 of "Neron models," so I am hopeful that the reference you've mentioned will end up very handy.

Comment: @user74230: Could you at least mention why $\psi$ and $\varphi$ in 9.2/9 and 9.2/10 are of finite type? This quasi-compactness feels "easy," albeit it is needed crucially in 9.2/13 (it would be nice to have the important 9.2/13 not depend on an incomplete proof). In 9.2/9, if I knew that $\mathrm{Ker}(\psi)$ is connected, I could fix its proof; likewise, if I knew that $\mathrm{Ker}(\psi)$ and $\mathrm{Ker}(\varphi)$ are quasi-compact, I could complete the proof of 9.2/13.

Comment: @QuestionMark: It is better that you extract this yourself by functorializing the arguments for 9.2/9,10 to get explicit representability by manifestly finite type group schemes (tori, etc.), but you could instead read the Expose XIII in SGA6 and in particular Theorem 3.5 there. Did you know connected lft group schemes over a field are qc? (This illustrates the point I emphasized earlier about figuring out this stuff for yourself after you learn more; just because you put "a number of hours" doesn't mean there is anything wrong with coming back to it in a year or two when you know more.)

Comment: @user74230: Thank you very much for the SGA6 reference! I am aware of the group scheme fact you've mentioned; in fact, I am using it crucially in my ad hoc fixes to 9.2/9 (I can't prove connectedness of the unipotent $\mathrm{Ker}(\psi)$ though). In 9.2/10, I can't prove that the kernel is actually a torus, but the rest is ok. I agree that it would be better to redo these arguments functorially, but at present I am not able to; maybe this will change with time.

Answer (score 2):

One may consult Corollary 12.5 in Oda, Seshadri "Compactifications of the generalized Jacobian variety" for a seemingly more complete argument.